# Are all assignments done through the setter in Ruby / Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails model that has a `belongs_to` relationship to another model.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

Every time a `bar` is set / updated on the `foo` I want "intercept" the modification of that change and update something on the `foo`.

My guess is that I can just override the setter for `bar` and do what I want. But, since I'm relatively new to Ruby / Rails, my concern is that there are "magical" ways that the `bar` can get set on the `foo` that don't go through my setter (perhaps with mass-assignment, update/update_all calls, etc).

What is the safest way to ensure that any change to `bar` runs a block of code that reacts to that change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can use callbacks on your bar to execute specific code on your foo.

All the documentation you need is here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

For example :

```
class Bar < ActiverRecord::Base
    has_many :foos
    before_save :do_something

    private
        def do_something
            self.foos.each {|f| f.update_attribute('bar_has_changed', true) }
        end
end
```

Comment: Trop rapide, je voulais répondre !

Comment: Haha, je me doutais qu'on se croiserais : ) J'en ai profité pour éditer tout ça !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've used callbacks quite a few times now, but why/when would I use a callback instead of overriding the setter. If callbacks are the safest way to go, why would you ever override a setter in Rails as opposed to writing a callback?

Comment: Callbacks are more precise when it comes to execute specific actions at a specific moment in the object's life. If you overrride the setter you execute some code only when the object is created. With callbacks, this can be done when the object has been validated for example. You can't do that at the initialization time.

Comment: @JavidJamae do a monkey-patch on the setters is not recommended. This is useful only if you serialize an attribute and you need to `eval` the input before saving it (attribute `config` serialized as Hash for exemple). The callbacks are here for modifying other attribute/objects related to the "current entry".

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the setter for `bar` is not a good idea.

Case in point:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar

  def bar=(value)
    # do nothing
  end
end

f = Foo.create
b = Bar.create
f.update_attributes(bar_id: b.id)
f.bar
# => #<Bar id: 1, ... >
```

Although the `bar` setter has been overridden so that it does nothing, you can get around that quite easily. The same goes for whatever custom update you implement on `Foo`: in cases like this one, it will not be called when the association is updated.

Use callbacks instead.